# Regular expression to flatten source code on multiple lines to one single line

Tags: regex, qt, qml

To reformat some code (Qt QML) I'm trying to achieve to go from this

```
SomeOuterTag{

    TableViewColumn {
            role: "property1"
            title: "property1"
    }

    TableViewColumn {
            role: "property2"
            title: "property2"
    }

}
```

to

```
SomeOuterTag{ 
    TableViewColumn {role: "property1"; title: "property1"}
    TableViewColumn {role: "property2"; title: "property2"}
}
```

I am trying to achieve this with regular expressions and substitutions (sublimeText/Perl copliant regex engine).

I manage to match the string contained into the Generic tag but not how to "unwrap" the line.

Initial version: https://regex101.com/r/gI0xC3/25

**[Update 1]**

This version prosed in the comments (stribizhev) does what I asked for but does not generalize when having a number of properties different from 2.

Regex: https://regex101.com/r/gI0xC3/27

Comment: why don't you just remove newline characters `\n` or replace them by spaces?

Comment: The issue I have is to select this newline character only it is in between the <Generic Tag name>{ ... } block as there is a ton of other source code that I don't want to be modified.

Comment: In SublimeText, try [`(?s)\h*(?:(\w+\s*\{)\s*([^\n]*)\h*\r?\n|(?!^)\G)\h*([^\n]*)\h*\s*(?=.*?\})`](https://regex101.com/r/iS4mQ8/1) and replace with `$1$2;$3`.